# How can I remove the space/ jump to the next line at the last of a for loop function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is stated in the question. Thanks

'''def=ABC
'''

```
import string

text=input('String: ')

y=[]

z=[]

m=[]

for i in text:

    if i in string.punctuation:

        y.insert(0,i)

    elif i in string.whitespace:

        y.insert(0,i)

    else:

        z.insert(0,i)

for k in z:

    m.insert(0,k)

for k in m:

    print(k, end='')
```

I expect the output of it to be ABC, but the actual output is ABC↵

Comment: `text = text.strip()`

Comment: your print statement does not add any return. Try `print("No return given")` after the `for kin m: print(k,end="")` loop ... your program probably terminates and the cosole flushes your output by default adding a return. Beside that - we can not replicate your problem and it is (to me) unclear what you input and what the `def=....` at the start does.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to define a function at the beginning or is it supposed to be a variable "def" that you do not use anywhere later? Your `print(k,  end='')` does not add a newline character at the end. There might be a more simple way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with your code, I got the following:

```
import string

is_punc = lambda ch, chs=string.punctuation:\
    ch in chs

is_white = lambda ch, chs=string.whitespace:\
    ch in chs

is_p_or_w = lambda ch, isw=is_white, isp=is_punc:\
    isw(ch) or isp(ch)

is_not_pw = lambda ch, ispw=is_p_or_w:\
    not ispw(ch)

text=input('String: ')

# `y` is a list of whitespace and punctuation
# characters from text.
# Duplicates are included. e.g. [".", ":", ".", "."]
# In list `y` chars appear in the reverse order
# of where they appeared in `text`

y = list(reversed(list(filter(is_p_or_w, text))))
z = list(reversed(list(filter(is_not_pw, text))))

# m = []
# for k in z:
#     m.insert(0,k)
m = list(reversed(z))

# `m` is a copy of `text` with
# all of the punctuation and white-space removed

for k in m:
    print(k, end='')
```

The code above is a mess, but it shows you some alternatives to what you originally were doing.

In the end, I recommend this:

import string

```
def remove_whitespace_and_punc(stryng):
    output = list()
    for ch in stryng:
        if ch in string.whitespace or ch in string.punctuation:
            ch = ""
        output.append(ch)
    return "".join(output)

text = input('String: ')
clean_text = remove_whitespace_and_punc(text)
print(clean_text, end="")
```